# What does "Gesehen PM40 Mittwoch" mean?

Tags: translation, word-usage, grammar-identification, time, austrian

I changed my iPhone language to German (Österreicher) recently because I want to learn as fast as possible and surround myself with the language. I noticed that in the Instagram DMs, under a person's name it says, e.g. "Gesehen PM40 Mittwoch". I understand that it means something like "seen Wednesday at [some time here]".

For the life of me, I cannot find what PM40 means and what it is. I suppose it's some way of AM/PM time tracking, or PM could stand for 'Private Message', but what does the 40 mean? Or any other number, as I have messages that say 38, 36 and so on.

I understand this might be a dumb/obvious question but I’m genuinely confused.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don’t you switch to English to check?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Instagram wording (especially abbreviations) has nothing to do with German language in the sense of this site.

Comment: A screenshot is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @Olafant I understand what you want to express - but do not block out a really great part of current everyday reality.

Comment: @PaulFrost I'n not blocking out anyone or anything. But I (German native) have absolutely no idea what *PM40* would mean. This is just not about German language but about Instagram UI.

Comment: I agree that "PM40" does not have any generally understandable meaning in German. I suspect it's just a localization error on Instagram's part.